# Hierarchical urls in Wordpress with no Taxonomy/post-type slug

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, slug

For example, if we have a domain called:
www.mydomain.com

And it's a website for gifts namely 3 categories: cards, pens, pencils

So if I were to get the URL like: 
a) www.mydomain.com/gifts/cards/
b) www.mydomain.com/gifts/cards/cards1/

Where;
a) 1) "gifts" is the page name that holds all the three categories (cards, pens, pencils)
b) 2) "cards" is one of the three categories clicked and showcases all the cards

b) 1) All above same just that "cards1" is the one of cards that have been clicked

Instead of the above URL I get:
a) www.mydomain.com/my-product_category/cards/
b) www.mydomain.com/my-product/cards1/

Where;
1) "my-product_category" is the taxonomy slug used for categories
2) "my-product" is the post-type slug used for category items

So all I want is to hide taxonomy and post-type slugs from all the URL's from the website.

I wish anyone could help me in this as I have been trying to figure this since couple of days. I hope my question is understandable.

Thanks in advance. 
Appy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your own styled permalinks from your WordPress dashboard. Go to your admin dashboard > settings > Permalinks. In common setting choose `Post Name` and in Optional section you can define your styled custom category structure and tag URLs. Hence your URLs will `yourdomain.com/products/cards`, where `products` is the page that holds all categories and `cards` will be your category. Optionally you can use woocommerce plugin for your products.

Comment: I have tried that it does not work at all. The main issue is that "cards1" page changes the URL completely. I want the URL to be **www.mydomain.com/gifts/cards/cards1** whereas it changes to **www.mydomain.com/my-product/cards1**

Comment: You only can define one Category base per installation.

Comment: I do understand that, but my question is that the URL should show in the following manner for the entire website: **www.mydomain.com/page/sub-page/portfolio-item** and **www.mydomain.com/page/portfolio-category** In other words the URL hierarchy should be maintained.

Comment: Can you link me to your website?

Comment: Sorry! I am under the process of building one. I might have been little difficult in explaining the problem. The issue is that the website should maintain the hierarchy of the page visited like if I were to visit a product (cards1) then it should just mask the original URL **(www.mydomain.com/my-product/cards1)** and instead show **(www.domain.com/gifts/cards/cards1)** or if I add one more page to the hierarchy then it should show **(www.domain.com/buy/gifts/cards/cards1)** and not **(www.domain.com/my-product/cards1)**

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my knowledge. The best place to ask this question is in WordPress forum. You can get help from experts there.